# Регулярное выражение для проверки строки версии (вроде 34.0.3, 23.2.*, 4.*)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, любой-язык

Нужно сделать регулярное выражение для проверки строки, обозначающей версию приложения. Строка имеет вид X.Y.Z, где X, Y, Z могут быть любыми целыми числами, а также * (кроме X). После символа * дальше строки быть не должно. Перед цифрами не должно быть 0.
Примеры валидных строк:

- 12.2323.2
- 0.0.3
- 0.0.0
- 34.0.3
- 23.2.*
- 4.*

Примеры неверных строк:

- 34а.34.1
- *
- 34.*.3
- 57.*.
- d3.43.3
- 0004.*
- 1.02.*

У меня такую регулярку сделать не вышло.

**Это не учебное задание**

Comment: "У меня не вышло" - просто слова. Поэтому закроем как учебное задание. Попробуйте сами **и выложите результат**. Мы увидим если это просто кусок с интернета, а не реальная попытка.

Comment: @Other, если бы я сам мог написать такую регулярку, этого вопроса бы тут не было

Comment: Мог и пытался - разные вещи. Вы же пока даже не пытались.

Comment: @Other, что вы от меня хотите? Чтобы я выложил набор нерабочих регулярок?

Comment: Не совсем. Нужно чтобы Вы выложили набор нерабочих регулярок, сказали чем они плохи и почему именно так, а не иначе Вы написали.

Comment: http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/VersionHelper.cs,51

Comment: @VladD, как всегда, самое просторе решение было где-то рядом :) Спасибо

Comment: @mirypoko: Ну, подключать целый пакет для этого всё же наверное слишком жирно. А стандартный `Version` сам по себе такого не умеет. // Хотя можно скопипастить код :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наивная реализация того что вы хотите:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(\*|(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(\*|(0|[1-9]\d*)))(\r)?$
```

---

Я получил ее следуя таким умозаключениям. Сперва составим регулярку, проверяющую строку на соответствие шаблону `A.B.C`, это просто:

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\r)?$
```

здесь `\d+` - любая цифровая последовательность, `\.` - точка (надо экранировать, да), `^` - начало строки, `(\r)?$` - конец строки, учитывающий как `\r\n`, так и просто `\n`

Далее, вместо последнего блока цифр может стоять единственная звездочка, заменяем `\d+` на `(\*|\d+)` (звездочку тоже надо экранировать):

```
^\d+\.\d+\.(\*|\d+)(\r)?$
```

Также звездочка может быть вместо последних двух блоков, аналогично предыдущему меняем `\d+\.(\*|\d+)` на `(\*|\d+\.(\*|\d+))`:

```
^\d+\.(\*|\d+\.(\*|\d+))(\r)?$
```

Ну и остается исключить числа с ведущими нулями, т.е. это либо отдельный ноль `0`, либо не ноль + несколько любых цифр `[1-9]\d*`. Заменяем все три блока `\d+` на конструкцию `(0|[1-9]\d*)`, получаем окончательный вариант.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(\*|((0|[1-9]\d*)\.(\*|(0|[1-9]\d*))))$
```

Немного пояснений:

ведущий ноль отсекаем таким выражением `0|[1-9]\d*`. Т.е. разрешаем или один ноль, или цифру 1-9, а за ней любое количество любых цифр.

`*` контролируем так `\*|((0|[1-9]\d*)\.(\*|(0|[1-9]\d*)))` или звездочка, или все остальное.

Тест на regex101 https://regex101.com/r/41aBtQ/1